# blueimp load files from server based on a prefix

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I use [bluimp](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) for file management, server side with php. 
When I upload the images I generate id's on each user and my file looks like

```
exmp. 12__filename.pdf
```

on next when I open bluimp interface I would like to load files based on my prefix 12__ and I do not find a way how can I pass this id `12` to bluimps php.

I see the trigger script but how can I pass extra parameters on load

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
                //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
                url: 'some url',
            });
```

**Update**

I got it working but is not the cleanest

I made some changes in Uploader class (php)

```
    protected function get_file_object($file_name) {
      $_GET['id]
      //and validate file_name
}
```

and I pass the parameter via url like `/some_url?id=12`

Answer (score 0):

Look for documentation:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    formData: {example: 'test'}
});
```

Comment: I think this one is used to submit extra form datas

Comment: You can pass anything to param. e.g: formData: {example: '["img\/test1.jpg","img\/test2.jpg","img\/test3.jpg"]'}